# QNAP - MySQL server SLOW response time / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache

We are going to use our QNAP as a Web Dev server.

We have the following:

1. TS-EC1279U-RP (Quad Core Intel Xeon E3-1225 3.1GHz Processor with 4GB ram & 12 HDDs in RAID 6)
2. PHP Version 5.3.9
3. MYSQL Server version: 5.1.36

We have installed Drupal and Joomla, however the response time seems to be very slows. We are waiting about 5 - 6 seconds before we get a response. We have edited the my.cnf for my sql (see below)

```
[client]
#password   = your_password
port = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-locking
skip-networking
skip-name-resolve

max_connections=500
key_buffer_size=384M
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=256
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=2M
join_buffer_size=2M

thread_cache=256

query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_size=32M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=128M
sort_buffer_size=128M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=128M
sort_buffer_size=128M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

However even with the change above recommended by different sites, the performance got better but just by a little.

We had our test sites on the QNAP and a hosting company. The response on the hosting company's servers is much faster. I know they have better hardware however the CPU charts on the QNAP dont even go above 3%.

Thank you

Update:

I have added the log-slow-queries. I have used the site for about 30 minutes: The results so far:

```
/usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld, Version: 5.1.36-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld, Version: 5.1.36-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

There is not indication that there is a SQL query longer than 1 second what so ever. So I am not sure to be honest if it is the PHP.ini or my.cnf setting.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your queries aren't optimized?

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html to identify your slow queries and try to optimize them.

Comment: @matt I do not think so. I have tried a FRESH install of joomla, drupal and word press. They all seem to be around 5-6 seconds and I also copied a production site. Same results. The live site is about 0.8 sec (real time) and the qnap is about 5-6 seconds. I will try the link you provided. Thank you

Comment: I did notice that under the process of phpMyAdmin it shows sleep for about 5-6 seconds. I think something is afoot but not sure.

Comment: In my experience, most of the time I get a slow response from the database is because a query isn't optimized. Make sure your tables are indexed properly after logging any slow queries and you'll see a HUGE performance increase (if indexing was the issue, of course).

Comment: @Matt Thanks Matt. Could you give me a few pointer please regarding indexing. I have just checked online about it, but I just want to make sure. Is it a process click n go or a far more complex.

Comment: Most GUIs have a point-click-type way of adding indexes to your columns. To figure out which columns *need* indexes, do an `EXPLAIN` on your queries (just type `EXPLAIN` before the `SELECT` and execute the query). Basically it will tell you how many rows were hit in each table when trying to execute the query. The high-hit tables require indexes on the comparison columns.

Comment: [This article might help you out.](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/do-you-always-need-index-on-where-column/)

Comment: @Matt I think something is strange here `Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 2.4148 sec )
CREATE TABLE `testr` (
`id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` varchar( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`has_something` tinyint( 3 ) unsigned NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
KEY `has_something` ( `has_something` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ` That a long time.....!!!

Comment: A `CREATE` took that long?!?!?! Something is definitely afoot and it's not just un-optimized queries.

Comment: Tried again... Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.1476 sec ) So not going to crazy... I will continue to investigate....

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit more sane-looking.

Comment: @Matt After doing a few test, created 500k records and searches, it not the my sql. Also with FRESH install of joomla / dupal. there would be no need to optimize or index the records at the present moment.

Comment: That's very strange. Still, it's not a bad idea to log slow queries. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with MYSQL and PHP. The problem was found.

Firstly I increased the PHP memory to 512M, overkill I know but that made a small difference.

The key was the website.

Application afterLoad: 0.000 seconds, 0.35 MB
Application afterInitialise: 0.020 seconds, 1.17 MB
Application afterRoute: 0.029 seconds, 1.36 MB
Application afterDispatch: 0.064 seconds, 2.03 MB
**Application afterRender: 6.15 seconds, 2.72 MB**

The issue was a RSS feed on the sites page. However after disabling it, the speed were fast as hell.

**Application afterRender: 0.126 seconds, 2.83 MB**

Thanks to matt for the ideas and support.